# Must reactjs keys be unique across an app

Tags: arrays, reactjs, key

I appologise if this is a duplicate question, but I can't seem to find the answer to it anywhere. I understand from various other questions that when using an array of components in reactjs, it is important that each component has a unique key.

**My Question**

If I have several arrays, for different parts of my page/app, does every element need a key that is unique with respect to every other element in the app, or does React only require that within each separate array there are no repeated keys?

Comment: They should only be unique within its siblings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have any link of some docs that explains that, but as I remember, a key must be unique on a parent's children.

Usually there is only one array of elements inside an element (so the keys must be unique in this array). But if there is something like:

```
<ul>
  {
    array1.each(element => <li key={element.uniqueId} />)
  }
  {
    array2.each(element => <li key={element.uniqueId} />)
  }
</ul>
```

Then the elements on array 1 and 2 must have a uniqueId between them. You could achieve this with:

```
<ul>
  {
    array1.each(element => <li key={"array1"+element.uniqueId} />)
  }
  {
    array2.each(element => <li key={"array2"+element.uniqueId} />)
  }
</ul>
```